# Issue creating OSM tile server using Docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, dockerfile, openstreetmap, docker-for-windows

I'm using OpenStreetMap tile server  @ the https://github.com/Overv/openstreetmap-tile-server to host my own tile server.

I run the container with the following command and it runs without error, however when I try to view the web page at localhost:8080 the map tiles do not load. When I view the network tab I can see they are getting a 404 error:

```
PS C:\Development\Uni> docker run -p 8080:80 -v openstreetmap-data:/var/lib/postgres/12/main -d overv/openstreetmap-tile-server run
```

I got a copy of the Docker logs to find out what was happening there:

```
+ '[' 1 -ne 1 ']'
+ '[' run = import ']'
+ '[' run = run ']'
+ rm -rf /tmp/hsperfdata_root
+ chown postgres:postgres /var/lib/postgresql -R
+ '[' '' == enabled ']'
+ '[' '' == 1 ']'
+ createPostgresConfig
+ cp /etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.custom.conf.tmpl /etc/postgresql/12/main/conf.d/postgresql.custom.conf
+ sudo -u postgres echo 'autovacuum = on'
+ cat /etc/postgresql/12/main/conf.d/postgresql.custom.conf
# Suggested minimal settings from
# https://ircama.github.io/osm-carto-tutorials/tile-server-ubuntu/

shared_buffers = 128MB
min_wal_size = 1GB
max_wal_size = 2GB
maintenance_work_mem = 256MB

# Suggested settings from
# https://github.com/openstreetmap/chef/blob/master/roles/tile.rb#L38-L45

max_connections = 250
temp_buffers = 32MB
work_mem = 128MB
wal_buffers = 1024kB
wal_writer_delay = 500ms
commit_delay = 10000
# checkpoint_segments = 60 # unrecognized in psql 10.7.1
max_wal_size = 2880MB
random_page_cost = 1.1
track_activity_query_size = 16384
autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor = 0.05
autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor = 0.02

listen_addresses = '*'
autovacuum = on
+ service postgresql start
 * Starting PostgreSQL 12 database server
   ...done.
+ service apache2 restart
 * Restarting Apache httpd web server apache2
[Mon Apr 27 20:29:40.317813 2020] [tile:notice] [pid 68:tid 140528325397440] Loading tile config ajt at /tile/ for zooms 0 - 20 from tile directory /var/lib/mod_tile with extension .png and mime type image/png
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
   ...done.
+ setPostgresPassword
+ sudo -u postgres psql -c 'ALTER USER renderer PASSWORD '\''renderer'\'''
ERROR:  role "renderer" does not exist
+ sed -i -E 's/num_threads=[0-9]+/num_threads=4/g' /usr/local/etc/renderd.conf
+ '[' disabled = enabled ']'
+ '[' disabled = 1 ']'
+ trap stop_handler SIGTERM
+ child=144
+ wait 144
+ sudo -u renderer renderd -f -c /usr/local/etc/renderd.conf
renderd[145]: Rendering daemon started
renderd[145]: Initiating request_queue
renderd[145]: Parsing section renderd
renderd[145]: Parsing render section 0
renderd[145]: Parsing section mapnik
renderd[145]: Parsing section ajt
renderd[145]: config renderd: unix socketname=/var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
renderd[145]: config renderd: num_threads=4
renderd[145]: config renderd: num_slaves=0
renderd[145]: config renderd: tile_dir=/var/lib/mod_tile
renderd[145]: config renderd: stats_file=/var/run/renderd/renderd.stats
renderd[145]: config mapnik:  plugins_dir=/usr/lib/mapnik/3.0/input
renderd[145]: config mapnik:  font_dir=/usr/share/fonts
renderd[145]: config mapnik:  font_dir_recurse=1
renderd[145]: config renderd(0): Active
renderd[145]: config renderd(0): unix socketname=/var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
renderd[145]: config renderd(0): num_threads=4
renderd[145]: config renderd(0): tile_dir=/var/lib/mod_tile
renderd[145]: config renderd(0): stats_file=/var/run/renderd/renderd.stats
renderd[145]: config map 0:   name(ajt) file(/home/renderer/src/openstreetmap-carto/mapnik.xml) uri(/tile/) htcp() host(localhost)
renderd[145]: Initialising unix server socket on /var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
renderd[145]: Created server socket 3
renderd[145]: Renderd is using mapnik version 3.0.19
renderd[145]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoSansDisplay-Italic.ttf
...
...
...
renderd[145]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto/NotoSansCJK-Bold.ttc
Running in foreground mode...
renderd[145]: Starting stats thread
debug: init_storage_backend: initialising file storage backend at: /var/lib/mod_tile
renderd[145]: Loading parameterization function for
debug: init_storage_backend: initialising file storage backend at: /var/lib/mod_tile
renderd[145]: Loading parameterization function for
debug: init_storage_backend: initialising file storage backend at: /var/lib/mod_tile
renderd[145]: Loading parameterization function for
debug: init_storage_backend: initialising file storage backend at: /var/lib/mod_tile
renderd[145]: Loading parameterization function for
Mapnik LOG> 2020-04-27 20:29:41: warning: unable to find face-name 'Noto Serif Tibetan Regular' in FontSet 'fontset-0'
...
...
...
Mapnik LOG> 2020-04-27 20:29:41: warning: unable to find face-name 'unifont Medium' in FontSet 'fontset-2'
renderd[145]: An error occurred while loading the map layer 'ajt': Postgis Plugin: FATAL:  role "renderer" does not exist
Connection string: ' dbname=gis connect_timeout=4'
  encountered during parsing of layer 'landcover-low-zoom' in Layer at line 825 of '/home/renderer/src/openstreetmap-carto/mapnik.xml'
renderd[145]: An error occurred while loading the map layer 'ajt': Postgis Plugin: FATAL:  role "renderer" does not exist
Connection string: ' dbname=gis connect_timeout=4'
  encountered during parsing of layer 'landcover-low-zoom' in Layer at line 825 of '/home/renderer/src/openstreetmap-carto/mapnik.xml'
renderd[145]: An error occurred while loading the map layer 'ajt': Postgis Plugin: FATAL:  role "renderer" does not exist
Connection string: ' dbname=gis connect_timeout=4'
  encountered during parsing of layer 'landcover-low-zoom' in Layer at line 825 of '/home/renderer/src/openstreetmap-carto/mapnik.xml'
renderd[145]: An error occurred while loading the map layer 'ajt': Postgis Plugin: FATAL:  role "renderer" does not exist
Connection string: ' dbname=gis connect_timeout=4'
  encountered during parsing of layer 'landcover-low-zoom' in Layer at line 825 of '/home/renderer/src/openstreetmap-carto/mapnik.xml'
```

Hopefully someone can make more sense of it than me but I did notice the following lines looked suspect:

```
+ sudo -u postgres psql -c 'ALTER USER renderer PASSWORD '\''renderer'\'''
ERROR:  role "renderer" does not exist

renderd[145]: An error occurred while loading the map layer 'ajt': Postgis Plugin: FATAL:  role "renderer" does not exist
Connection string: ' dbname=gis connect_timeout=4'
  encountered during parsing of layer 'landcover-low-zoom' in Layer at line 825 of '/home/renderer/src/openstreetmap-carto/mapnik.xml'
```

I think it is an issue with the Docker install so this is the Docker file for reference (also I'm using Docker for Windows):

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# Based on
# https://switch2osm.org/manually-building-a-tile-server-18-04-lts/

# Set up environment
ENV TZ=UTC
ENV AUTOVACUUM=on
ENV UPDATES=disabled
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install wget gnupg2 lsb-core -y \
  && wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add - \
  && echo "deb [ trusted=yes ] https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ `lsb_release -cs`-pgdg main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list \
  && apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates 

RUN apt-get install -y curl \
  && wget --quiet -O - https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash - \
  && apt-get install -y nodejs

RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
  apache2 \
  apache2-dev \
  autoconf \
  build-essential \
  bzip2 \
  cmake \
  cron \
  fonts-noto-cjk \
  fonts-noto-hinted \
  fonts-noto-unhinted \
  gcc \
  gdal-bin \
  git-core \
  libagg-dev \
  libboost-filesystem-dev \
  libboost-system-dev \
  libbz2-dev \
  libcairo-dev \
  libcairomm-1.0-dev \
  libexpat1-dev \
  libfreetype6-dev \
  libgdal-dev \
  libgeos++-dev \
  libgeos-dev \
  libgeotiff-epsg \
  libicu-dev \
  liblua5.3-dev \
  libmapnik-dev \
  libpq-dev \
  libproj-dev \
  libprotobuf-c0-dev \
  libtiff5-dev \
  libtool \
  libxml2-dev \
  lua5.3 \
  make \
  mapnik-utils \
  node-gyp \
  osmium-tool \
  osmosis \
  postgis \
  postgresql-12 \
  postgresql-contrib-12 \
  postgresql-server-dev-12 \
  protobuf-c-compiler \
  python3-mapnik \
  python3-lxml \
  python3-psycopg2 \
  python3-shapely \
  sudo \
  tar \
  ttf-unifont \
  unzip \
  wget \
  zlib1g-dev \
&& apt-get clean autoclean \
&& apt-get autoremove --yes \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/{apt,dpkg,cache,log}/

# Set up PostGIS
RUN wget https://download.osgeo.org/postgis/source/postgis-3.0.0.tar.gz -O postgis.tar.gz \
 && mkdir -p postgis_src \
 && tar -xvzf postgis.tar.gz --strip 1 -C postgis_src \
 && rm postgis.tar.gz \
 && cd postgis_src \
 && ./configure && make && make install \
 && cd .. && rm -rf postgis_src

# Set up renderer user
RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" renderer

# Install latest osm2pgsql
RUN mkdir -p /home/renderer/src \
 && cd /home/renderer/src \
 && git clone https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql.git \
 && cd /home/renderer/src/osm2pgsql \
 && rm -rf .git \
 && mkdir build \
 && cd build \
 && cmake .. \
 && make -j $(nproc) \
 && make install \
 && mkdir /nodes \
 && chown renderer:renderer /nodes \
 && rm -rf /home/renderer/src/osm2pgsql

# Install mod_tile and renderd
RUN mkdir -p /home/renderer/src \
 && cd /home/renderer/src \
 && git clone -b switch2osm https://github.com/SomeoneElseOSM/mod_tile.git \
 && cd mod_tile \
 && ./autogen.sh \
 && ./configure \
 && make -j $(nproc) \
 && make -j $(nproc) install \
 && make -j $(nproc) install-mod_tile \
 && ldconfig \
 && cd ..

# Configure stylesheet
RUN mkdir -p /home/renderer/src \
 && cd /home/renderer/src \
 && git clone https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto.git \
 && git -C openstreetmap-carto checkout v4.23.0 \
 && cd openstreetmap-carto \
 && rm -rf .git \
 && npm install -g carto@0.18.2 \
 && carto project.mml > mapnik.xml \
 && scripts/get-shapefiles.py \
 && rm /home/renderer/src/openstreetmap-carto/data/*.zip

# Configure renderd
RUN sed -i 's/renderaccount/renderer/g' /usr/local/etc/renderd.conf \
 && sed -i 's/\/truetype//g' /usr/local/etc/renderd.conf \
 && sed -i 's/hot/tile/g' /usr/local/etc/renderd.conf

# Configure Apache
RUN mkdir /var/lib/mod_tile \
 && chown renderer /var/lib/mod_tile \
 && mkdir /var/run/renderd \
 && chown renderer /var/run/renderd \
 && echo "LoadModule tile_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_tile.so" >> /etc/apache2/conf-available/mod_tile.conf \
 && echo "LoadModule headers_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_headers.so" >> /etc/apache2/conf-available/mod_headers.conf \
 && a2enconf mod_tile && a2enconf mod_headers
COPY apache.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
COPY leaflet-demo.html /var/www/html/index.html
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/apache2/access.log \
 && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/apache2/error.log

# Configure PosgtreSQL
COPY postgresql.custom.conf.tmpl /etc/postgresql/12/main/
RUN chown -R postgres:postgres /var/lib/postgresql \
 && chown postgres:postgres /etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.custom.conf.tmpl \
 && echo "host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5" >> /etc/postgresql/12/main/pg_hba.conf \
 && echo "host all all ::/0 md5" >> /etc/postgresql/12/main/pg_hba.conf

# Copy update scripts
COPY openstreetmap-tiles-update-expire /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/openstreetmap-tiles-update-expire \
 && mkdir /var/log/tiles \
 && chmod a+rw /var/log/tiles \
 && ln -s /home/renderer/src/mod_tile/osmosis-db_replag /usr/bin/osmosis-db_replag \
 && echo "*  *    * * *   renderer    openstreetmap-tiles-update-expire\n" >> /etc/crontab

# Install trim_osc.py helper script
RUN mkdir -p /home/renderer/src \
 && cd /home/renderer/src \
 && git clone https://github.com/zverik/regional \
 && cd regional \
 && git checkout 612fe3e040d8bb70d2ab3b133f3b2cfc6c940520 \
 && rm -rf .git \
 && chmod u+x /home/renderer/src/regional/trim_osc.py

# Start running
COPY run.sh /
COPY indexes.sql /
ENTRYPOINT ["/run.sh"]
CMD []

EXPOSE 80 5432
```

Comment: have you resolved this error?

Comment: I downloaded a different osm.pbf file and changed the name of the volume to something different and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a different volume name from the example provided as this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I use these setup options on the latest version. Everything works :

```
docker run -e DOWNLOAD_PBF=http://download.geofabrik.de/europe-latest.osm.pbf -v map-data:/var/lib/postgresql/14/main overv/openstreetmap-tile-server import
```

then

```
docker run -p 8080:80 -v openstreetmap-data:/var/lib/postgresql/14/main -d overv/openstreetmap-tile-server run.
```